# Post throwing 500 error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm writing a small app. Here is the code snippet.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filldata()
{
    var sample = document.getElementById("filter-select").value;
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.post("/test",{"filter_type":sample},function(data,status)
    {
    alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

**Flask Code:**

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test(str):
    return str
```

It is giving me `500 internal error`.
When I run this in debug mode, it is saying:

```
test() takes exactly one argument(zero given)
```

Comment: i suggest you to use fiddler in cases like this, so you can read an error in your response. You are submitting field with name `filter_type`, but do you have field with that name on your server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test(str):
    return str
```

Expect a variable named str in input.
With flask, when defining route the arguments of the function represent the *url* variables:

```
# the url have a parameter
@app.route('/user/<id>',methods=['GET'])
    def test(id): # we get it here
        return user.fromId(id)
```

To retrieve querystring you can use `request.args`. And to get body `request.data` or `request.json` if you are sending json.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return request.data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cybril :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse argument from Flask's [request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data) object

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return request.form.get('filter_type')
```

See [quickstart](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#the-request-object) for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Flask code snippet, you have added an argument, but arguments are only sent if you change the URL to `/test/<str:str>`. Since it is a POST request, you can access the data by using `request.json`.